# Questions about if $\dim(U)\ge\dim(V)−\dim(W)$ and proving $∃T∈\mathfrak{L}(V,W) \text{s.t.}\text{null}(T)=U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have two problems listed below, but here is the question:

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional and that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Prove that there exists $T\in\mathfrak{L}(V,W)$ such that $\text{null}(T)=U$ if and only if $\text{dim}(U)\geq\text{dim}(V)-\text{dim}(W)$.

I have proved the forward direction, but have a few questions for the backwards direction:

But first, here is my proof of the backwards direction:

Let $(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ be a basis for $U$, which can then be extended to a basis in $V$, namely, $(u_1,\dots,u_m,v_1\dots,v_n)$. Also, let $(w_1,\dots,w_p)$ be a basis for $W$. So then by the hypothesis, $m\geq(m+n)-p$ which means $n\leq p$.

Now we shall define the following:

$Tu_j=0$ for j in 1,...,m

and $Tv_i=w_i$ for i in 1,...,n

Then, we have $T(a_1u_1 + · · · + a_mu_m + b_1v_1 + · · · + b_nv_n)$ = $b_1w_1 + · · · + b_nw_n$.

Now I have two BIG questions:

First, what is the significance of having $n\leq{p}$? Is it to make sure that our our $m+n$ dimensional vector generated by the basis in V doesnt get mapped to something of higher dimension than itself? Does $n\leq{p}$ imply we have a linear map? Is that the only thing it helps us realize?

Also, if I were to have $n>p$, would this imply that I am nullifying the additivity principle of linear maps and thus creating more elements?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n > p$ you would not be able to define $Tv_i=w_i$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ with different values. So that $Tv_j = Tv_k$ for some $j$, $k$, and $v_j - v_k \in \text{null}(T) \setminus U$.